# How to attach a scroll bar from tool box to a panel so that it expands in relation to the form/panel?

Tags: c#-2.0

I have dragged a scroll bar on a panel on my form. Now i want to bind that scroll bar with the form. such that whenever i expand my form the scorll bar expands and remains at the right (incase of vertical scroll bar) and at bottom(in case of horizontal scroll bar).
What is happening right now is that the scroll bar remains at the place where i had positioned it even if i resize or maximize the form. Help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the Size events of the form.

When the form size changes, you move your scrollbar so it stays flush right, and change the length of the scrollbar so it's always correct.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain a bit more there.